# Access iPhone's sandbox Document folder from standard C++ code

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, boost, qt-creator

I'm deploying an iphone application through QtCreator. I'd like to create a simple file using standard C++ libraries. I try to do this in the sandbox Documents folder.

I compiled `boost`, so I use this library to check if the sandbox Document folder exists.

My application starts in `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/<application name>.app`. Then, I simply try to access `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/<application name>.app/../Documents` folder (using `boost::filesystem::is_directorty`), as it does not exist, I try to create it (using `boost::filesystem::create_directories`), but it fails (boost raises an exception).

Am I doing it wrong? Am I not in the right PATH? Or do I have to set any special permission to my app in order to be able to do this (as for Android, I add to list EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my application manifest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My path for documents was wrong. Could find the good one using Qt API:

```
QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
```

This returns:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<another UUID>/Documents
```

(different than what I was trying to access in `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application`)